# Unable to update the event using REST API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, journeybuilder

So basically, According to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/updateEventDefinition.html), I can update my event using the key or the id of the event

So I created an API using the REST API, it is created and used in a Journey, now, I want to update the name of that event.

I tried to update the event in three cases :

- Before using the event in a Journey
- While the Journey is running
- After Stopping the Journey

I always get the same error

```
{
    "message": "{{{ERROR_OPEN_SUPPORT_CASE}}}",
    "errorcode": 30000,
    "documentation": "Need more help regarding this error? Open a support case through the <a target='_blank' href='https://help.salesforce.com/mysuccesshub?id=solutionFinder'>Help &amp; Training Portal</a>"
}
```

It seems meaningless message, because it does not help really.

So the JSON sent to Route is this :

```
{
    "name":"EVENT TP BE UPDTAED",
    "eventDefinitionKey": "API-25523077930328154002",
    "dataExtensionId": "0617e8e8-221b-ed11-b85d-f40343c97959",
    "sourceApplicationExtensionId":"7db1f972-f8b7-49b6-91b6-fa218e13953d"
}
```

First I tried with the name only because that's all I want, updating the name and nothing more but I had doubts that maybe I have to provide everything, even though I guess the key or the id on the URL is enough for this.

So the DE-Id is the same id that is used during the creation of the event, as well as the sourceAPPid

For the name and eventKey, I tried to change them, I set a new name, I tried to set the same name as well, same goes for the eventKey

Bu still get same confusing error.

Comment: I would advise to create a support ticket.

Comment: It is solved, I had to specify the Type and VisibleInPicker propertioes again, it isn't documented ( as many things in SFMC ), but worked